# DockPanel - Stretch control to fill remaining space in respect to it's siblings Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dockpanel

The following snippet produces this result:

```
<DockPanel Width="240">
    <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <ComboBoxItem Content="A" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="B" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="C" />
    </ComboBox>
</DockPanel>
```

[image]

As we can see, the `ComboBox` fills the entire `DockPanel` width nicely, as it's supposed to be.
If we add the following `StackPanel` right after the `ComboBox`, we would have this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="120" Visibility="Visible" Background="Aqua">
    <TextBox Width="60" />
    <TextBox Width="60" />
</StackPanel>
```

[image]

We've just got into the first problem: shouldn't the `ComboBox` fill the other 120 pixels of the `DockPanel`, due to it's `HorizontalAlignment=Stretch` and since the `StackPanel` uses the other 120?

Least, if we turn our `StackPanel.Visibility` into `Hidden/Collapsed`, we would have this:

[image]

How can I make the `ComboBox` to fill the entire `DockPanel.Width` **HORIZONTALLY**, just like the first image, when the `StackPanel.Visibility` is `Hidden/Collapsed`?

All the controls must be horizontally aligned and a `DockPanel` isn't mandatory to achieve this.

Comment: Use Visibility.Collapsed instead of Hidden.

Comment: @DaveM have you tried running a sample with your solution? Neither hidden or collapsed works.

Comment: Put the combo box as the last thing in the dock panel (after the stack panel) and set the stack panel’s DockPanel.Dock=“Right”

Comment: Dockpanel seems convenient. In practice it can be fiddly getting things to work as expected and layout can be fragile. Grid is much more predictable.

Answer (score 0):

> We've just got into the first problem: shouldn't the `ComboBox` fill the other 120 pixels of the `DockPanel`, due to it's `HorizontalAlignment=Stretch` and since the `StackPanel` uses the other 120?

Only if it the *last* child of the `DockPanel`:

```
<DockPanel Width="240">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="120" Visibility="Visible" Background="Aqua"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right">
        <TextBox Width="60" />
        <TextBox Width="60" />
    </StackPanel>
    <ComboBox>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="A" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="B" />
        <ComboBoxItem Content="C" />
    </ComboBox>
</DockPanel>
```

There is no reason to explicitly set the `HorizontalAlignment` property to `Stretch` by the way. This is the default value.

> How can I make the `ComboBox` to fill the entire `DockPanel.Width` HORIZONTALLY, just like the first image, when the `StackPanel.Visibility` is `Hidden`/`Collapsed`?

By adding the `ComboBox` as the last child as per the above sample markup.

Answer (score -1):

If i understand you, in your case it seems that `Grid` component will be a good choice.

For the space issue - 
`Visibility = "Hidden"` keeps the original component space "alive", then if it possible - use `Visibility = "Collapsed"` instead

```
 <Grid Width="240">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="A" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="B" />
            <ComboBoxItem Content="C" />
        </ComboBox>
        <StackPanel  Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Horizontal"  Visibility="Visible" Background="Red">
            <TextBox Width="60" />
            <TextBox Width="60" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Still the `ComboBox` does not take the column 2 space when the `StackPanel` is hidden/collapsed.

Comment: well, i have just tested it and as i wrote, Visibility = "Hidden" is not going to work but  when Visibility = "Collapsed" the `ComboBox` is taking the whole remaining space (240px). please check it again

Comment: If you collapse the stackpanel it will take no space and it's in an auto column which will in turn take no space. If you just hide it then it takes up the same space but you can't see it. Looks to me like collapsed would therefore work. If collapsed doesn't work for some reason then please update your post with enough code and markup so we can replicate what you see easily.